# ngOnChanges() not working after data update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ngonchanges

I have a problem with updating value using `NgOnChanges`.

I am sharing data between components using `@Input()` decorator.

Component 1 html:

```
 <div class="container-right">
    <app-transaction-details [clickedElement] = clickedElement></app-transaction-details>
</div>
```

Component 2

```
@Input() clickedElement?: Transaction
```

Clicked element is a tr row which is selected and passed after click.

```
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
            class="single-row" (click) = "clickedElement = row" ></tr>
```

Now in my Component 2 I want to invoke function every time that clickedElement data changes.
I have tried implement `OnChanges` interface but it doesn't work - `getPossibleBalance()` is called only if I select different row.

```
 export class TransactionDetailsComponent implements OnChanges {
  
  @Input() clickedElement?: Transaction
  possibleBalance = ""

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if(changes.clickedElement){
      this.possibleBalance = this.getPossibleBalance()
    }
  }
```

So my question is what am I doing wrong?